# Deduplicate Google Photos photos

Tags: google-photos

Is there an easy way to deduplicate Google Photos photos? All of the examples on Google are for [Google +](https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=deduplicate%20google%20photos%20photos) and/or Picasa.

EDIT: I'm not storing google photos in my google drive, because then they count against my google drive quota.

Comment: For the moment, the advice for Google+ is still valid, since the photos "live" in both places. So, if you can get to your photos at https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/yourphotos, you can manage your duplicates there.

Comment: There is probably a way to take care of this using a separate application if you have the Google Photos stored in your Google Drive. What OS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Google Photos saved in your Google Drive, you should be able to install the Google Drive for Mac / PC to get the folder 'mounted' on your computer.

[Google Drive Installer](https://www.google.com/drive/download/)

From there, you can use an application such as dupeGuru (which works on Mac and Windows). You should be able to scan the Google Photos folder within your Google Drive and find the duplicates.

> **dupeGuru Actions --**
>   Do whatever you want with your duplicates. Not only can you delete duplicates files dupeGuru finds, but you can also move or copy them elsewhere. There are also multiple ways to filter and sort your results to easily weed out false duplicates (for low threshold scans).

[dupeGuru](https://dupeguru.voltaicideas.net/)

[image: dupeGuru screenshot]

Comment: Caution: [dupeGuru is deprecated](https://www.howtogeek.com/200962/how-to-find-and-remove-duplicate-files-on-windows/).  "Many websites recommend dupeGuru as one of the best duplicate file finder tools, but it’s no longer officially supported on Windows. You shouldn’t download an old version of dupeGuru anymore, either—the developer says he’s seen reports of bugs on Windows 10 and doesn’t have time to fix them."